# getting exact mousejoint release position of a sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

How can I get the exact position of a sprite at the time a mousejoint moving it is released (even though the sprite might still be moving). I believe it should be coded in the ccTouchesEnded method, but I am not sure how to do it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to know is where the sprite is when you release a tap then do this:

```
-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint pos = sprite.position;
}
```

Comment: please take a look at this follow up [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883147/cclog-not-displaying)